# Using Ruby to automate a large directory system

Tags: ruby, arrays, file-io, ruby-1.9

So I have the following little script to make a file setup for organizing reports that we get.

```
#This script is to create a file structure for our survey data

require 'fileutils'

f = File.open('CustomerList.txt') or die "Unable to open file..."
a = f.readlines
x = 0

while a[x] != nil

    Customer = a[x]
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(Customer + "/foo/bar/orders")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(Customer + "/foo/bar/employees")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(Customer + "/foo/bar/comments")
    x += 1

end
```

Everything seems to work before the `while`, but I keep getting:

```
'mkdir': Invalid argument - Cust001_JohnJacobSmith(JJS) (Errno::EINVAL)
```

Which would be the first line from the `CustomerList.txt`. Do I need to do something to the array entry to be considered a string? Am I mismatching variable types or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is "Cust001_JohnJacobSmith(JJS)" the first line?

Comment: Yes, that would be the first line from the file.

Comment: I even tried just using `mkdir_p(a[x])' and I get the same error.

Comment: could you try simply 

FileUtils.mkdir_p("Cust001_JohnJacobSmith(JJS)/foo/bar/orders")
 first, perhaps in irb or the first line of your script. This works for me.

Comment: That works just fine, so I guess it's something that is captured in each line?

Comment: yeah, I would guess something to do with the newlines. Could you do "puts 'customer:' + Customer.inspect" and paste the first one?  Anyway, see the answer for a more Ruby-like version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
IO.foreach('CustomerList.txt') do |customer|
  customer.chomp!
  ["orders", "employees", "comments"].each do |dir|
    FileUtils.mkdir_p("#{customer}/foo/bar/#{dir}")
  end
end
```

with data like so:

```
$ cat CustomerList.txt 
Cust001_JohnJacobSmith(JJS)
Cust003_JohnJacobSmith(JJS)
Cust002_JohnJacobSmith(JJS)
```

A few things to make it more like the ruby way:

Use blocks when opening a file or iterating through arrays, that way you don't need to worry about closing the file or accessing the array directly.

As noted by @inger, local vars start with lower case, customer.

When you want the value of a variable in a string usign #{} is more rubinic than concatenating with +.

Also note that we took off the trailing newline using chomp! (which changes the var in place, noted by the trailing ! on the method name)

Comment: Worked great. Thanks so much. Looks like I'll need to do a little Ruby reading soon.